# System.Object[] in CSV File

Tags: powershell, csv

I have read all I can read but I just don't get what the problem is when exporting  something from PowerShell to a CSV and getting System.Object[]

This is just a section of code I use to extract missing updates from servers that are managed by SCCM. The Switch Array is there because I need to have the SCCM Deployment Unique ID translated into a "Friendly" name I use to identify that patching collection.

This works fine and is displayed correcting on the screen (I just do this for testing the Switch array to ensure it is working by putting `$Updates` in the script). However, when I attempt to export to a CSVfile, I get the `System.Object[]` underneath the column titles.

I know I could pipe the first line, then select the objects in the `$TargetedUpdates` array, and export them without any problem. But this only gives me the SCCM Deployment Unique ID with the server. I need to "resolve" this to a friendly name that makes sense in the CSV file. How can this be accomplished?

```
$TargetedUpdates = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from CCM_TargetedUpdateEX1 where UpdateState = 0" -Namespace root\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\DeploymentAgent -Computer ifdpv02 


ForEach-Object {

$MissingUpdates = $TargetedUpdates.RefAssignments.TrimEnd(";")


$MonthlyPatch = switch ($MissingUpdates){

            "{0C3267EE-F343-4577-B1A3-C24FA0406DDF}" {"October 2014 Patching for Test\DEV Servers"} 
            "{D849903A-4594-4D72-9224-39DC2ABA22E}"  {"October 2014 Patching for Production Servers"}
            "{A3F0E8A2-FB2F-4045-8E22-7726007844E6}" {"October 2014 Patching for Manual Servers"} 
            "{DC3991B7-30EB-4529-AA63-537968A651D0}" {"October 2014 Patching for New Server Builds"}
            "{7C263094-4DA3-4AB8-9F79-0C169EA18D6D}" {"October 2014 Patching for Manual Test Servers"}
            "{39EDE4AD-71C9-4393-B849-498C6D677FFF}" {"October 2014 Patching for Test\SQL Servers"}
            #**********************************************************************************************
            #**********************************************************************************************
            default {"This is a System Center Endpoint Protection Update"}  
            }


$Updates = New-Object PSobject
$Updates | Add-Member NoteProperty Server ($TargetedUpdates.PScomputerName)
$Updates | Add-Member NoteProperty MonthlyPatch $MonthlyPatch
$Updates
$Updates | Export-Csv C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation 

}

Invoke-Item C:\temp\test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: You are not processing each update *individually*.

Unfortunately I am not familiar with the data structure of your WMI return to know if this is going to work. You need to send data to the `foreach-object` loop to process is the *main* thing.

```psh
$TargetedUpdates = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from CCM_TargetedUpdateEX1 where UpdateState = 0" -Namespace root\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\DeploymentAgent -Computer ifdpv02 

$TargetedUpdates | ForEach-Object {
    $MissingUpdates = $_.RefAssignments.TrimEnd(";")

    $MonthlyPatch = switch ($MissingUpdates){
        "{0C3267EE-F343-4577-B1A3-C24FA0406DDF}" {"October 2014 Patching for Test\DEV Servers"} 
        "{D849903A-4594-4D72-9224-39DC2ABA22E}"  {"October 2014 Patching for Production Servers"}
        #TRUNCATED AS IT IS TOO LONG**********************************************************************************************
        default {"This is a System Center Endpoint Protection Update"}  
    }

    $Updates = New-Object PSobject
    $Updates | Add-Member NoteProperty Server ($TargetedUpdates.PScomputerName)
    $Updates | Add-Member NoteProperty MonthlyPatch $MonthlyPatch
    $Updates
}  | Export-Csv C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

We loop each update individually create an object for each. Those are then sent to the `Export-CSV` for output.

**Another Approach**

Instead of the `switch` in the loop you could use a hashtable that stores all your id and friendly names and then use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to make the object for you rather easily.

```
$friendlies = @{
    "{0C3267EE-F343-4577-B1A3-C24FA0406DDF}" = "October 2014 Patching for Test\DEV Servers"
    "{D849903A-4594-4D72-9224-39DC2ABA22E}" = "October 2014 Patching for Production Servers"
    # Add more here obviously. 
}


$server = "ifdpv02" 
$TargetedUpdates = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from CCM_TargetedUpdateEX1 where UpdateState = 0" -Namespace root\ccm\SoftwareUpdates\DeploymentAgent -Computer $server
$TargetedUpdates | Select-Object @{Label="Server";Expression={$server}},
        @{Label="MonthlyPatch";Expression={$friendlies[$_.RefAssignments.TrimEnd(";")]}} |
        Export-Csv C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

*Caveat for both solution here:*

Like I said earlier I do not know the data structure. If `RefAssignments` returns as array we need to add some more logic but it can be done.

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying, sorry.

Comment: RefAssignments is a object when WMI is queried from the First line in what I gave. It reveals the SCCM DeploymentID that the server is non-compliant on.
 
I don't understand why it prints the information on the screen perfectly but everything is lost when exporting to CSV.

Comment: I can't even post a screen shot or the results to give you a better idea what is going on. I am really struggling with the value of this site.

Comment: @Habanagold Have you tried any of my code that I have shown you? I want to help but I don't have your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved the problem by changing my variable for $MonthlyPatchAssignment. Excuse me for the clutter, the code I will post here is much different than I originally posted. The key seems to be grabbing the variable in the pipeline ($*.RefAssignments) and putting that into my Swich array. Before I was trying to take that same variable but make it equal to another variable (i.e. $MissingUpdates = $*.RefAssignments.TrimEnd(";"))

Now I am getting the correct value instead of System.Object[] in my CSV file

```
$MonthlyPatchAssignment =  switch ($_.RefAssignments.TrimEnd(";")) { 
                              
        "{0C3267EE-F343-4577-B1A3-C24FA0406DDF}" {"October 2014 Patching for Test\DEV Servers"} 
        "{D849903A-4594-4D72-9224-39DC2ABA22E}"  {"October 2014 Patching for Production Servers"}
        "{A3F0E8A2-FB2F-4045-8E22-7726007844E6}" {"October 2014 Patching for Manual Servers"} 
        "{DC3991B7-30EB-4529-AA63-537968A651D0}" {"October 2014 Patching for New Server Builds"}
        "{7C263094-4DA3-4AB8-9F79-0C169EA18D6D}" {"October 2014 Patching for Manual Test Servers"}
        "{39EDE4AD-71C9-4393-B849-498C6D677FFF}" {"October 2014 Patching for Test\SQL Servers"}

            default {"This is a System Center Endpoint Protection Update"}  

        }

      $NonCompliantDetail = New-Object PSobject
      $NonCompliantDetail | Add-Member NoteProperty Server    $($_.PScomputerName)
      $NonCompliantDetail | Add-Member NoteProperty PatchName $MonthlyPatchAssignment
      $NonCompliantDetail | Add-Member NoteProperty BullentinID $uBulletinID
      $NonCompliantDetail | Add-Member NoteProperty Description $uTitle
      $NonCompliantDetail | Export-Csv C:\Temp\sccm\"$FileNamePreface"_MissingUpdatesRAW.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: I tried to format my code, but I guess I need a manual on how to use the formatting features. I tried highlighting all of my code and selecting the code option but didn't appear to do anything.

Indented 4 spaces worked. Guess I don't understand the formatting junk when it pops up. TOO BUSY to make sense for me.